# Can I project an optional reference of an entity into an optional reference of the projection's result type?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Say, I have two entities:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SalesLevel { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public string ShippingRemark { get; set; }

    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

`Customer` is an *optional* (nullable) reference in `Order` (maybe the system supports "anonymous" orders).

Now, I want to project some properties of an order into a view model including some properties of the customer **if** the order has a customer. I have two view model classes then:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int SalesLevel { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class OrderViewModel
{
    public string ShippingRemark { get; set; }
    public CustomerViewModel CustomerViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

If the `Customer` would be a *required* navigation property in `Order` I could use the following projection and it works because I can be sure that a `Customer` always exists for any `Order`:

```
OrderViewModel viewModel = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Id == someOrderId)
    .Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        ShippingRemark = o.ShippingRemark,
        CustomerViewModel = new CustomerViewModel
        {
            SalesLevel = o.Customer.SalesLevel,
            Name = o.Customer.Name
        }
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

But this does not work when `Customer` is optional and the order with Id `someOrderId` does not have a customer:

- EF complains that the materialized value for `o.Customer.SalesLevel` is `NULL` and cannot be stored in the `int`, not nullable property `CustomerViewModel.SalesLevel`. That's not surprising and the problem could be solved by making `CustomerViewModel.SalesLevel` of type `int?` (or generally *all* properties nullable)
- But I would actually prefer that `OrderViewModel.CustomerViewModel` is materialized as `null` when the order has no customer.

To achieve this I tried the following:

```
OrderViewModel viewModel = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Id == someOrderId)
    .Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        ShippingRemark = o.ShippingRemark,
        CustomerViewModel = (o.Customer != null)
            ? new CustomerViewModel
              {
                  SalesLevel = o.Customer.SalesLevel,
                  Name = o.Customer.Name
              }
            : null
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

But this throws the infamous LINQ to Entities exception:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'CustomerViewModel'. Only
>   primitive types (for instance ''Int32', 'String' und 'Guid'') are
>   supported in this context.

I guess that `: null` is the "constant value" for `CustomerViewModel` which is not allowed.

Since assigning `null` does not seem to be allowed I tried to introduce a marker property in `CustomerViewModel`:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public bool IsNull { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

And then the projection:

```
OrderViewModel viewModel = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Id == someOrderId)
    .Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        ShippingRemark = o.ShippingRemark,
        CustomerViewModel = (o.Customer != null)
            ? new CustomerViewModel
              {
                  IsNull = false,
                  SalesLevel = o.Customer.SalesLevel,
                  Name = o.Customer.Name
              }
            : new CustomerViewModel
              {
                  IsNull = true
              }
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

This doesn't work either and throws the exception:

> The type 'CustomerViewModel' appears in two structurally incompatible
>   initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be
>   initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same
>   properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the
>   same order.

The exception is clear enough how to fix the problem:

```
OrderViewModel viewModel = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Id == someOrderId)
    .Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        ShippingRemark = o.ShippingRemark,
        CustomerViewModel = (o.Customer != null)
            ? new CustomerViewModel
              {
                  IsNull = false,
                  SalesLevel = o.Customer.SalesLevel,
                  Name = o.Customer.Name
              }
            : new CustomerViewModel
              {
                  IsNull = true,
                  SalesLevel = 0, // Dummy value
                  Name = null
              }
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

This works but it's not a very nice workaround to fill all properties with dummy values or `null` explicitly.

Questions:

1. Is the last code snippet the only workaround, aside from making all properties of the `CustomerViewModel` nullable?
2. Is it simply not possible to materialize an optional reference to `null` in a projection?
3. Do you have an alternative idea how to deal with this situation?

(I'm only setting the general *entity-framework* tag for this question because I guess this behaviour is not version specific, but I am not sure. I have tested the code snippets above with EF 4.2/`DbContext`/Code-First. Edit: Two more tags added.)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? and if so would you mind sharing :)

Comment: @QuintonBernhardt: No, I didn't find a solution. I workaround this mainly by making all nested view model properties nullable.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot get the projection to work on the IQueryable implementation of DbQuery either.  If you're looking for a workaround then why not do the projection after the data has been retrieved from the Db and it's not an E.F. DbQuery anymore...

```
OrderViewModel viewModel = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Id == someOrderId)
     // get from db first - no more DbQuery
    .ToList()
    .Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        ShippingRemark = o.ShippingRemark,
        CustomerViewModel = o.Customer == null ? null : new CustomerViewModel
        {
            SalesLevel = o.Customer.SalesLevel,
            Name = o.Customer.Name
        }
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

The downside is you're fetching all the Order and Customer columns from the Db.  You can limit this by selecting only the columns you require from Order into an anonymous type and then...

```
OrderViewModel viewModel = context.Orders
    .Where(o => o.Id == someOrderId)
    .Select(o => new { ShippingRemark = o.ShippingRemark, Customer = o.Customer })
     // get from db first - no more DbQuery
    .ToList()
    .Select(o => new OrderViewModel
    {
        ShippingRemark = o.ShippingRemark,
        CustomerViewModel = o.Customer == null ? null : new CustomerViewModel
        {
            SalesLevel = o.Customer.SalesLevel,
            Name = o.Customer.Name
        }
    })
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I am aware of both workarounds. The first one is terrible, to be honest. I would have to use `Include` for the customer in addition to loading all order properties (or lazy loading which would cause multiple queries) and then throw most of the loaded properties away in memory when I project. The second one is OK, just more code to write, but not really what I was looking for. Nonetheless +1 for the example in part 2 :) BTW: I normally use `AsEnumerable()` instead of `ToList()` to switch from LINQ to Entities to LINQ to Objects. It has a bit less overhead.