# Testing EF ConcurrencyCheck

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, concurrency

I have a base object, that contains a Version property, marked as ConcurrencyCheck

```
public class EntityBase : IEntity, IConcurrencyEnabled
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ConcurrencyCheck] 
    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] Version { get; set; }
}
```

This works, however, I want to write a test to ensure it doesn't get broken.  Unfortunately, I can't seem to figure out how to write a test that doesn't rely on the physical database!

And the relevant test code that works, but uses the database...

```
    protected override void Arrange()
    {
        const string asUser = "ConcurrencyTest1"; // used to anchor and lookup this test record in the db

        Context1 = new MyDbContext();
        Context2 = new MyDbContext();
        Repository1 = new Repository<FooBar>(Context1);
        Repository2 = new Repository<FooBar>(Context2);
        UnitOfWork1 = new UnitOfWork(Context1);
        UnitOfWork2 = new UnitOfWork(Context2);

        Sut = Repository1.Find(x => x.CreatedBy.Equals(asUser)).FirstOrDefault();

        if (Sut == null)
        {
            Sut = new FooBar
                {
                    Name = "Concurrency Test"
                };

            Repository1.Insert(Sut);
            UnitOfWork1.SaveChanges(asUser);
        }

        ItemId = Sut.Id;
    }

    protected override void Act()
    {
        _action = () =>
            {
                var item1 = Repository1.FindById(ItemId);
                var item2 = Repository2.FindById(ItemId);

                item1.Name = string.Format("Changed @ {0}", DateTime.Now);
                UnitOfWork1.SaveChanges("test1");

                item2.Name = string.Format("Conflicting Change @ {0}", DateTime.Now);
                UnitOfWork2.SaveChanges("test2"); //Should throw DbUpdateConcurrencyException
            };
    }

    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(DbUpdateConcurrencyException))]
    public void Assert()
    {
        _action();
    }
```

How can I remove the DB requirement???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend extracting your MyDbContext into an interface `IMyDbContext`, and then creating a TestDbContext class that will also implement SaveChanges the way you have it up there, except with returning a random value (like 1) instead of actually saving to the database.

At that point then all you'd need to do is to test that, in fact, all of the entities got their version number upped.

Or you could also do the examples [found here](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2011/05/31/faking-dbcontext.aspx) or [here](http://romiller.com/2012/02/14/testing-with-a-fake-dbcontext/), as well.

EDIT: I actually just found a direct example with using TimeStamp for concurrency checks on [this blog post](http://www.remondo.net/entity-framework-concurrency-checking-with-timestamp/).

Comment: I don't want to test that the version number was upped.  I want to test that the exception is thrown by EF.

Comment: Then check out the last link that I just posted.

Comment: It's using a real database, which is what I want to avoid in my test.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right. You don't even want to have a testing database? I'm not sure you can do concurrency checks without a physical database. This blog post seems to suggest that the concurrency check happens on the database itself: http://sankarsan.wordpress.com/2010/08/29/entity-framework-concurrency/

Comment: I'm not reading it that way, I'm reading it as "if the query returns 0 rows updated" EF assumes it's a concurrency exception.  It's not that the DB actually does any concurrency checking. So I shouldn't actually need a physical database.

Comment: Right, but EF actually needs to go to the physical database in order to figure out that it needs to throw that exception.

Comment: Why?  Can't some in memory mock do it?

Comment: So then how about combining the ideas from the 1st and 3rd links? Create a fake DbContext that has HashSets to store the data in memory, and then simulate EF getting back that concurrency exception by checking to see if the TimeStamp had changed at all from the record currently in the HashSet.

Comment: I'm need to implement way too much for it to work, and then it's still not testing what I want, as I'm writing the check for a concurrency exception, instead of testing that EF will throw it...

Comment: If you want to test that EF will throw it then you'll need to use a physical database. There doesn't appear to be a way around that.

Answer (score 0):

It's my opinion that you should not try to mock this behaviour to enable "pure" unit testing. For two reasons:

- it requires quite a lot of code that mocks database behaviour: materializing objects in a way that they have a version value, caching the original objects (to mock a store), modifying the version value when updating, comparing the version values with the original ones, throwing an exception when a version is different, and maybe more. All this code is potentially subject to bugs and, worse, may differ slightly from what happens in reality.
- you'll get trapped in circular reasoning: you write code specifically for unit tests and then... you write unit tests to test this code. Green tests say everything is OK, but essential parts of application code are not covered.

This is only one of the many aspects of linq to entities that are hard (impossible) to mock. I am compiling a list of these differences [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13352779/861716).