# What are the ways to make property code-generated only

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to create an abstract class which will contain properties and every entity in my solution will inherit this properties.

I do want that abstract class properties to be restricted from any user modification except the changes which are made by code.

What I want to achieve:

```
public abstract class SystemEntityBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the date when entity was created.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime Created { get; } = DateTime.UtcNow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the date when entity was last active in the system.
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime LastActive { get; } = DateTime.UtcNow;
}
```

Because I am using read-only property, the EntityFrameworkCore will not add this fields to my database table when auto-generating the migration scripts.

I am curios what are possible solutions to restrict properties in my case while also create the database columns?

Comment: Does `[ReadOnly(true)]` help at all?

Comment: You may also like [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52021425/861716).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use init only properties if you can use c# 9.0.

Comment: Init properties require c# 9 **and** either .net 5 or a manual copy of the necessary mod-req type. Definitely worth a try - I'm just saying it isn't *just* c# 9 that is needed.

Comment: But user still will be able to set the property value by `new SomeEntity {Created = ....}` which is not what OP wants as I understand.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood problem correctly - you can try using [Backing Fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field?tabs=fluent-api). For your `Created` property it can look something like that (for some reason using `BackingFieldAttribute` didn't work for me with my test SQLite and postgres setups, but fluent API did the trick):

```
public class SomeEntity
{
    public DateTime Created => _created

    private DateTime _created = DateTime.UtcNow;    
}
```

And in `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)`:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
     .Property(b => b.Created)
     .HasField("_test");
```

Also it is possible to remove the need to setup all `SomeEntity`'s by hand via some reflection magic.