# Position entity framework columns after all columns

Tags: entity-framework-core, migration

I am trying to create a class which all my entities will extend in order to ensure that all required columns are there such as `CreatedAt`, `UpdatedAt`, `Id`.

I am trying to get the timestamps **after** all columns, however using the order inside of the `Column` attribute this does not seem to be working, but I believe this to be because all my other columns don't have an order on but I think this is a bit laboursome so was trying to do this automatically from the base class.

```
public class BaseEntity 
{
   public int Id { get; set; }

   [Column("CreatedAt", Order = 9998 )]
   public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

   [Column("UpdatedAt", Order = 9999 )]
   public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Is there anyway to automatically doing this without having to specify the order on every property?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add the same column to all entities in EF Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020107/how-to-add-the-same-column-to-all-entities-in-ef-core)