# Why does everyone wants to do unit tests with the entity framework and not integration tests

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, integration-testing

Many people so I read in google strive for unit-testing the repository classes with a so called in-memory database compared to integration tests with a real database.

Where is the problem of doing the latter?

Comment: To the guy who gave me a -1. I have read the first time about this topic and did not find the supplied link so why then deserves this good question a punishment?

Comment: Easily solved :) +1 since I agree, good question, even while it's a duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

If you are using EF, you don't have to write tests to see whether EF persist data correctly or not. So you don't need a real database for the testing, all you need to test is your code logic and in-memory database is best suitable in this case, it helps to separate of concerns, flexible, easy to run and run faster than using a real database.

Furthermore, running integration tests with a real database is quite complex. It requires some configuration(connection string, drop and re-create database...) before running which may take time. The tests may fail because of mis-configuration(e.g. using shared database during testing) and it takes time to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you are testing against an in memory database or real database you are not doing unit tests - both are integration tests. Both will actually test some form of connection and provider implementation.

The main benefits I would see of using an in memory database vs a real database are

- Permissions - using a real database will usually require higher level of permissions and connectivity. Like file writing permissions or access to a database server. An in memory database may not require the same level of permissions.
- Speed - it is quicker to spin up and tear down an in memory database than a real database

Depending on your pattern (i.e. if you're using a unit of work), it is likely that you don't even need a database to test your repositories.

Comment: yes I use the unit of work pattern. So I do not need a real or in-memory database. Please clarify that.

Comment: You could abstract your DbContext and try to mock IQueryable as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332002/how-to-mock-the-limitations-of-entityframeworks-implementation-of-iqueryable

Comment: But then I will just end up like in the link you posted me. Doing only Unit-Test is not enough the link says. Therefore I want to do at first integration tests thats enough for me.