# Database First ID, EmployeeID to be called id

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, repository, entity-framework-5, unit-of-work

I have database first entities with different primary id names... EmployeeID, CustomerID etc.  I am attempting to build a generic repository and UoW and want to know if there is anyway, without changing the database, to tell the UoW that every primary id in database, i.e. employeeid etc, will just be called id?

Thanks

I guess my question wasn't clear, so I will try an example of what I need to do.  Thanks for your patience.

I have 3 tables, customer, orders and orderdetails, 
The customer table has a primary key field CustomerID.
The orders table has a primary key field OrderID
The orderdetails table has a primary key field orderdetailsid.

I have 3 entities, generated from edmx, that represent each table.

I have a generic repository and unit of work to monitor save changes.  I would like to have a generic way of saying that the customerid primary key will be known as id, the orderid primary key will also be known as id, and lastly the orderdetailsid will also be known as id.

I believe using a generic will allow me to create an interface that will return the primary key.

```
 public interface IEntity {
    int Id { get; }
 }
```

I believe I can go through all my entities in the designer and change the primary key name without affecting the database, but that would be real time consuming when there may be a way of doing this within the application.

Thanks

Comment: What do you need this for? I ask, because I can imagine some scenario's for which there could be alternative ways to achieve them.

Comment: I wanted to create add on repositories where I didn't have to worry about the ID name.

Comment: If you add, you don't need an Id, or you can use [`AddOrUpdate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) if you work with DbContext.

Comment: I would like to put findById in a generic repository and then just have to call below for all my entities.

     public T FindById(int id)
        {
            return _objectSet.Single(o => o.Id == id);
        }

Comment: If you work with DbContext API (do you?) you can use the [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method.

Comment: I am using DbContext, but it is Database First.  I have only been able to find repository and uow examples for Code First, so I am trying to modify examples for database first.  So far, not having much success.

Comment: DbContext is what counts here. It means you can use AddOrUpdate. Further, I'm not a fan of generic repositories, look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15535416/861716) (among others) and see if you still need them. Nevertheless it should be possible to find examples if you focus on DbContext + generic repository.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the only way to achieve  this type of mapping is to set the column name either through fluent configuration using model builder or by setting the column name using the Data Annotations API on your models

ie Data Annotations

```
[Column("EmployeeId")]
public int ID { get; set; }
```

or Fluent 
In your Context class

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

     modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().Property(e=>e.Id).HasColumnName("EmployeeId");

     base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

but this would require you to not use edmx or write a inherited DbContext to customize your you may also want to look into Entity framework power tools to remove the dependency on designers while maintaining your abiliy to quickly generate your entity classes which will make your classes more customizable as far as mapping your entity

Another option in the latter case you could write a DbConvention that would customize your mappings as well this article provides some examples of writing custom Database conventions for Entity framework http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj819164.aspx