# Why isn't DbSet covariant?

Tags: entity-framework, covariance

I have a factory function to return a `DbSet(Of IItemType)`.  The actual return type will always be an implementation `IItemType`, for example `DbSet(Of CategoryType)`.

I thought covariance is supported in generics and this method would work fine, but I get an exception when I try to run my code:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[CategoryType]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1[IItemType]'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DbSet<T>` CANNOT be co-variant. Firstly, this is because in C#, classes cannot be co-variant...only interfaces. Secondly because `DbSet<T>` has both co-variant and contra-variant methods.

Take the following two examples.

```
DbSet<CategoryType> set = context.Set<CategoryType>();
IQueryable<IItemType> query = set.Where(x => x.Foo == Bar);
```

So we know for a fact that all `CategoryType`s are `IItemType`, so we know this can always work.

However conversely try this...

```
DbSet<CategoryType> set = context.Set<CategoryType>();
IItemType newItemType = new ProductType();
set.Add(newItemType);  // Compiler error.
```

Not all `IItemType`s are `CategoryType`. So if we could cast `DbSet<CategoryType>` to `DbSet<IItemType>` we would get run time errors when adding... Since the compiler knows that this might not always work, it won't let you do the casting.

However there are interfaces that `DbSet<T>` does allow Co-Variance on. You can try casting it to `IQueryable<IItemType>` for example.

However it sounds like you are trying to query against the DbSet using a query against the interface... try the following

```
DbSet<CategoryType> set = context.Set<CategoryType>();
IQueryable<IItemType> cast = set.OfType<IITemType>(); //(or .Cast<>() works too)
IQueryable<IItemType> query = cast.Where(x => x ....);
```

Comment: Your first statement is not entirely correct. You can use the `out` keyword in generic interface and delegate definitions only, but classes that implement these interfaces _are_ covariant: _Covariance and contravariance are supported for reference types, but they are not supported for value types._ ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx)). I admit I had to look it up. My answer to your comment above wasn't quite correct either.

Comment: But it is the usage of those Interfaces that is covariant/contravariant. You can't cast a `DbSet<T>` to `DbSet<TBase>` because not all `TBase` can be ADDED to the underlying `DbSet<T>`. Similarly you can't cast `DbSet<T>` to `DbSet<TDerivied>` since it may contain items in the underlying of `TOtherDerivied`, when you query it.

Comment: IQueryable<> is a good solution. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Aron - It's 7 years later and I just rediscovered my own question while looking up `DbSet` covariance.  Now I see how helpful your solution would have been if I had understood it at the time!  Great insight on using `IQueryable<IItemType>` to get the covariant behavior I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like they could be covariant. But there is a [host of differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332002/how-to-mock-the-limitations-of-entityframeworks-implementation-of-iqueryable/13352779#13352779) between in-memory programming and programming against a query provider.

For Entity Framework to materialize an object from the data store it requires its *exact* type and the mapping from database columns to the type's properties. An interface can represent *any* type and EF is not (yet) able to pick a suitable implementation itself. Maybe support for interfaces will be featured in future releases.

The same applies to casting entities to an interface in an EF query (a case I just added to my list of differences).

Comment: Does that mean the `Cast` call gets added to the `Expression` before its executed?  So EF tries to translate the `Cast` call into some kind of SQL and obviously cannot because there is no `IItemType` in the DB.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what happens.

Comment: Is there a way to instruct EF to apply the cast *after* querying the DB?  I want a `DbSet` so I can use all the functionality (`Add`, `Remove`, etc), so I don't want to use something like `ToList` to buffer it.

Comment: Yes, you can use `AsEnumerable`, but I don't see how you could use that to return a `DbSet(Of IItemType)`.

Comment: @Aron Sure, slip of the keyboard. There is no `out` keyword.