# Entity Framework Generic Inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, inheritance

I'm trying to assign a `DbSet` of class that is inherited from a more generic class. The example below demonstrates what I'm trying to achieve:

```
DbSet<Animal> dbSet;

switch (selectedAnimal)
{
    case "Dog":
        dbSet = _Context.Dog; // DbSet<Dog>
        break;
    case "Cat":
        dbSet = _Context.Cat; // DbSet<Cat>
        break;
    case "Pig":
        dbSet = _Context.Pig; // DbSet<Pig>
        break;
}
```

The `Dog`, `Cat`, `Pig` class is an inherited class of `Animal`, as follows:

```
public class Dog : Animal { }
```

But I am getting a compile-time error of 
`Cannot implicitly convert type DbSet<Dog> to DbSet<Animal>`

How can I implement my design without getting the error?

P.S. The code above is just to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve, so forgive me if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19082671/why-isnt-dbset-covariant

Comment: Interesting.. Covariance is something new to me, will read up about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're referring to is called covariance. In C# only interfaces can be covariant. So `IEnumerable<Cat>` is a subtype of `IEnumerable<Animal>`. The problem with declaring a `DbSet<Animal>` and then putting a variable of type `DbSet<Cat>` in it is that a variable of type `DbSet<Animal>` has methods that allow, for instance, adding an `Animal` entity. That `Animal` might be a `Dog`. But the variable you put in there was a `DbSet<Cat>` and that can't contain `Dog`. It would be a violation of strong typing.

Comment: So according to what you are saying, will it work if I change `Animal` into an interface? It doesn't seem to work even after changing `Animal` from a class to interface.

Comment: No, I'm saying that it would work if `DbSet` were an interface (and if it were declared in a certain manner, read the wiki page on covariance and contravariance). What you're trying to do can't be done.

Answer (score 1):

Because compiler cant cast derived classes to base class w/o information loss.
You simply cant put DbSet of Cat into DbSet of Animal where Cat : Animal

But you CAN put DbSet of Animal into DbSet of Cat

Try this one:

```
var dbSet = GetDbSet(selectedObject) //selectedObject is Cat,Dog,Pig whatever
```

And the method:

```
    private DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>(T selectedAnimal) where T : Animal
    {
        return this.Set<T>(); //this == EF Context
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I'm trying to set a DbSet of derived class into a DbSet of base class, which according to @ChrisV, covariance. I don't see how your answer can do that, thanks anyway!