# How to validate Linq2Object as Linq2Entity queries?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, entity-framework-4.1

I need my implementation of `IObjectSet<T>` to be able to **validate expressions** as the "real" Linq2Entity provider would. Is it possible?

**Background**:
I've changed my EF model (model-first) to return `IObjectSet<T>` instead of `ObjectSet<T>`
So that I can fake my model, and have it return the data I want.

**Problem**:
I have written an implementation of `IObejctSet<T>` that is bacally a wrapper for a `List<T>`.
This is all good - **but** when I query my implementation of `IObjectSet<T>` im using LinqToObject - so there is no guarantee that I have *valid* Linq2Entity expression.

**Proposed solution**:
use the real 
In my implementaion i just use `List<T>`'s provider:

```
private class IObjectSetUnitTestImplementation<T> : IObjectSet<T> where T : EntityObject
{
  private IQueryable _qry;

  public IObjectSetUnitTestImplementation(List<T> lst)
  {
    _inner = lst;
    _qry = _inner.AsQueryable();
    Expression = _qry.Expression;
    ElementType = _qry.ElementType;
    Provider = _qry.Provider; //<--should be ObjectSet<T>'s provider
  }
  //Rest of implementaion omitted
}
```

So I tried this:

```
ObjectContext context = null;
var _qry = new ObjectQuery<T>(typeof(T).Name, context) as IQueryable;
Expression = _qry.Expression;
ElementType = _qry.ElementType;
Provider = _qry.Provider;
```

But I have no context to feed it with, and even if I had, it would just try to access the database.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> so there is no guarantee that I have valid Linq2Entity expression"

Congratulations, you've just discovered a reason, why `IObjectSet<T>`, `IRepository<T>` and etc. shouldn't be implemented for `IQyeryable<T>`. And the reason is simple: query, which is valid for one LINQ provider, can be invalid for another one (even if you just change databases from MS SQL to something other).

And there's no generic way to verify those queries.
So, unit-testing isn't a good choice for `IQyeryable<T>`, but **integration** testing is a definitely the thing that you need.

Comment: I have [heard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904139/fake-dbcontext-of-entity-framework-4-1-to-test) this argument before, but I was hoping someone found a solution. I just dont understand *why* its not possible

Comment: @JensKloster: this isn't possible because of LINQ providers nature. The first provider supports feature `A`, the second - doesn't. To validate an expression with this feature you need to build query from it via LINQ provider, and query construction means "query execution".

Comment: Im upvoting your answer because the deeper I dive into this problem, the more your answer makes sence :) Still hoping that someone will come up with a solution though..

Comment: I fount [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13332002/how-to-mock-the-limitations-of-entityframeworks-implementation-of-iqueryable/13352779#13352779) - so you where right :) thank you