# Why does this combination of Select, Where and GroupBy cause an exception?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a simple table structure of services with each a number of facilities. In the database, this is a `Service` table and a `Facility` table, where the `Facility` table has a reference to a row in the Service table.

In our application, we have the following LINQ working:

```
Services
    .Where(s => s.Facilities.Any(f => f.Name == "Sample"))
    .GroupBy(s => s.Type)
    .Select(g => new { Type = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
```

But for reasons beyond my control, the source set is projected to a non-entity object before the `Where` call, in this way:

```
Services
    .Select(s => new { Id = s.Id, Type = s.Type, Facilities = s.Facilities })
    .Where(s => s.Facilities.Any(f => f.Name == "Sample"))
    .GroupBy(s => s.Type)
    .Select(g => new { Type = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
```

But this raises the following exception, with no inner exception:

`EntityCommandCompilationException: The nested query is not supported. Operation1='GroupBy' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'`

Removing the `Where`, however, makes it work, which makes me believe it's only in this specific combination of method calls:

```
Services
    .Select(s => new { Id = s.Id, Type = s.Type, Facilities = s.Facilities })
    //.Where(s => s.Facilities.Any(f => f.Name == "Sample"))
    .GroupBy(s => s.Type)
    .Select(g => new { Type = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
```

Is there a way to make the above work: select to an non-entity object, and then use `Where` and `GroupBy` on the resulting queryable? Adding `ToList` after the `Select` works, but the large source set makes this unfeasible (it would execute the query on the database and then do grouping logic in C#).

Comment: And which database and EF version are we talking about?

Comment: SQL Server 2014 and Entity Framework 6.1.1!

Comment: Made this question part of my [LINQ-to-entites != LINQ-to-objects collection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13352779/861716).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This exception originates from this piece of code in the EF source...

```
// <summary>
// Not Supported common processing
// For all those cases where we don't intend to support
// a nest operation as a child, we have this routine to
// do the work.
// </summary>
private Node NestingNotSupported(Op op, Node n)
{
    // First, visit my children
    VisitChildren(n);
    m_varRemapper.RemapNode(n);

    // Make sure we don't have a child that is a nest op.
    foreach (var chi in n.Children)
    {
        if (IsNestOpNode(chi))
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(Strings.ADP_NestingNotSupported(op.OpType.ToString(), chi.Op.OpType.ToString()));
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

I have to admit: it's not obvious what happens here and there's no technical design document disclosing all of EF's query building strategies. But this piece of code...

```
// We can only pull the nest over a Join/Apply if it has keys, so
// we can order things; if it doesn't have keys, we throw a NotSupported
// exception.
foreach (var chi in n.Children)
{
    if (op.OpType != OpType.MultiStreamNest
        && chi.Op.IsRelOp)
    {
        var keys = Command.PullupKeys(chi);

        if (null == keys
            || keys.NoKeys)
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException(Strings.ADP_KeysRequiredForJoinOverNest(op.OpType.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Gives a little peek behind the curtains. I just tried an `OrderBy` in a case of my own that exactly reproduced yours, and it worked. So I'm pretty sure that if you do...

```
Services
    .Select(s => new { Id = s.Id, Type = s.Type, Facilities = s.Facilities })

    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)

    .Where(s => s.Facilities.Any(f => f.Name == "Sample"))
    .GroupBy(s => s.Type)
    .Select(g => new { Type = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
```

the exception will be gone.

Comment: This fixed the problem entirely, brilliant! Thank you for digging into the source code, it was not obvious to me where to look given the exception.