# The nested query is not supported. Operation1='GroupBy' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

This is the linq which run in linqpad iam not getting any error,but when i run our project iam getting this error(The nested query is not supported. Operation1='GroupBy' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'),Can u pls give the soln

```
  var ledgerReport = (from i in db.Items
             join si in db.SalesInvoiceDetails on i.ItemCode equals si.ItemCode
             join cat in db.categories on i.catCode equals cat.catCode
             join locw in
                 (from loc in db.LocationStocks
                  group loc by new { loc.ItemCode } into g1
                  select new { Qty1 = (Decimal?)g1.Sum(x => x.Qty) ?? 0, g1.Key.ItemCode }) on i.ItemCode equals locw.ItemCode into we
             where si.DispatchDate >= startdate && si.DispatchDate <= enddate
             group si by new
             {
                 si.ItemCode,
                 i.Description,
                 Qtt = (Decimal?)we.Sum(x => x.Qty1) ?? 0,
                 i.LowestLevel
             } into g
             select new
             {
                 g.Key.ItemCode,
                 g.Key.Description,
                 qoh = g.Key.Qtt,
                 quantity = (Decimal?)g.Sum(x => x.QtyOrdered) ?? 0,
                 lowlevel = g.Key.LowestLevel
             }).tolist();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old question, but it has a few upvotes and no answer, and Google sent me here. It took forever, but I finally found a solution, and thought it would be nice to share in case anyone else is desperate. :)

Try putting an arbitrary orderby into the Linq. In the case of this example, I think it would look like:

```
         group si by new
         {
             si.ItemCode,
             i.Description,
             Qtt = (Decimal?)we.Sum(x => x.Qty1) ?? 0,
             i.LowestLevel
         } into g
         orderby g.ItemCode
         select new
         {
             g.Key.ItemCode,
             g.Key.Description,
             qoh = g.Key.Qtt,
             quantity = (Decimal?)g.Sum(x => x.QtyOrdered) ?? 0,
             lowlevel = g.Key.LowestLevel
         }).tolist();
```

Could also try it in that db.LocationStocks nested query, but for me it was putting orderby into the top level that did it.

My best guess is that the orderby triggers some different handling for the nested query. There was another idea to [rewrite the join in a different way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38743577/the-nested-query-is-not-supported-entity-framework-fails-on-grouped-left-joins), but that didn't work for me. The [post I found this solution in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27152545/why-does-this-combination-of-select-where-and-groupby-cause-an-exception) also made me think that adding a foreign key between the tables in question could do it, but I didn't try that out.