# The nested query is not supported: Entity Framework fails on grouped left joins

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

Consider this query:

```
from e in db.MyEntities

join o in db.MyOtherEntities
on new e.Foo equals o.Foo into others
from o in others.DefaultIfEmpty()

select new
{
  Value1 = e.Value1,
  Value2 = o.Value2
};
```

With this simple left join, Entity Framework fails on doing the following group

```
from e in query group e by new { } into g select g.Count()
```

That may seem obscure, but it's actually a common thing for automatic grid implementations to do with your queries.

I encountered this using DevExtreme's data library: Total summaries wouldn't work on queries with left joins.

What you get is a

```
NotSupportedException: The nested query is not supported. Operation1='GroupBy' Operation2='MultiStreamNest'
```

This works though:

```
from e in query.Take(1) select { Count = query.Count(), /* other aggregates */ }
```

And so does this:

```
from e in query group e by e.SomePropertyThatsActuallyConstant into g select g.Count()
```

Comment: "don't bother answering" is not a good thing to write, there's nothing wrong with other people adding their own answers, even if you intent to self-answer.

Comment: What can I say, I'm a bad guy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround. You can write your query like this:

```
from e in db.MyEntities

from o in db.MyOtherEntities.Where(o => o.Foo == e.Foo).DefaultIfEmpty()

select new
{
  Value1 = e.Value1,
  Value2 = o.Value2
};
```

Strangely it also works when you put a where clause after the join:

```
from e in db.MyEntities

join o in db.MyOtherEntities
on new e.Foo equals o.Foo into others
from o in others.DefaultIfEmpty()

where e.Value1 == e.Value1

select new
{
  Value1 = e.Value1,
  Value2 = o.Value2
};
```

The where clause condition must not be merely constants, I guess EF is smart enough to reduce it otherwise.