# How to efficiently fetch distant relation in Entity Framework projection

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to write a LINQ/Entity Framework projection that will pull back two fields from a distant relation. For all the purposes of this question, I have these structure:

**PlayedGame**

- `int Id` (PK)
- `List<PlayerGameResult> PlayerGameResults`

**Player**

- `int Id` (PK)
- `string Name`

**PlayerGameResult**

- `PlayedGame PlayedGame` (FK to PlayedGame)
- `Player Player` (FK to Player)

For a given played game, I want to fetch the Name and Player Id of one arbitrary Player that was in that played game. In reality my example is a little bit more complicated, but I'm leaving out the details since they are a distraction.

The following projection is the best I could come up with:

```
 var result = dataContext.GetQueryable<PlayedGame>()
    .Where(playedGame => playedGame.Id == somePlayedGameId)
    .Select(x => new
        {
            Name = x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault() != null ? x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault().Player.Name : null,
            Id = x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault() != null ? x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault().Player.Id : 0
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

... but the underlying SQL that is generated is moderately terrifying to me:

```
SELECT
    [Limit5].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Limit5].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Limit5].[C2] AS [C2]
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP (1) 
         [Project11].[Id] AS [Id], 
         CASE WHEN ([Project11].[C1] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Project11].[Name] END AS [C1], 
         CASE WHEN ([Project11].[C2] IS NOT NULL) THEN [Project11].[C3] ELSE 0 END AS [C2]
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
        [Project9].[Id] AS [Id], 
        [Project9].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Project9].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project9].[C2] AS [C2], 
        (SELECT TOP (1) 
            [Extent6].[PlayerId] AS [PlayerId]
            FROM [dbo].[PlayerGameResult] AS [Extent6]
            WHERE [Project9].[Id] = [Extent6].[PlayedGameId]) AS [C3]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project8].[Id] AS [Id], 
            [Project8].[Name] AS [Name], 
            [Project8].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project8].[C2] AS [C2]
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project6].[Id] AS [Id], 
                [Project6].[Name] AS [Name], 
                [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
                (SELECT TOP (1) 
                    [Extent5].[Id] AS [Id]
                    FROM [dbo].[PlayerGameResult] AS [Extent5]
                    WHERE [Project6].[Id] = [Extent5].[PlayedGameId]) AS [C2]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project5].[Id] AS [Id], 
                    [Extent4].[Name] AS [Name], 
                    [Project5].[C1] AS [C1]
                    FROM   (SELECT 
                        [Project3].[Id] AS [Id], 
                        [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
                        (SELECT TOP (1) 
                            [Extent3].[PlayerId] AS [PlayerId]
                            FROM [dbo].[PlayerGameResult] AS [Extent3]
                            WHERE [Project3].[Id] = [Extent3].[PlayedGameId]) AS [C2]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [Project2].[Id] AS [Id], 
                            [Project2].[C1] AS [C1]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
                                (SELECT TOP (1) 
                                    [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id]
                                    FROM [dbo].[PlayerGameResult] AS [Extent2]
                                    WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[PlayedGameId]) AS [C1]
                                FROM [dbo].[PlayedGame] AS [Extent1]
                                WHERE [Extent1].[Id] = @p__linq__0
                            )  AS [Project2]
                        )  AS [Project3] ) AS [Project5]
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Player] AS [Extent4] ON [Project5].[C2] = [Extent4].[Id]
                )  AS [Project6]
            )  AS [Project8]
        )  AS [Project9]
    )  AS [Project11]
)  AS [Limit5]
```

Is there a "better" way to write this projection? In other words, how can I write this query in LINQ / Entity Framework to only pull back these two fields from the Player table in a fashion that will produce a decent/sane query? I won't pretend to know for certain that the above query is terrible -- but it just doesn't seem in the ballpark to me.

Looking forward to your thoughts!

Comment: It would be worth adding the LINQ you've used so far that generated that SQL.

Comment: @webnoob thanks for noticing that. I completely forgot, but went ahead and added it yesterday after you mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entire LINQ statement is translated into SQL, which means that you don't have to worry about null checks. SQL doesn't have a concept of null reference (we might say, it had null propagation right from the start!). So your statement can be simplified to:

```
var result = dataContext.GetQueryable<PlayedGame>()
    .Where(player => player.Id == testPlayerWithNoPlayedGames.Id)
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Name = x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault().Player.Name,
        Id = (int?)x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault().Player.Id
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Query syntax can make it look less complex:

```
var result = (from playerGame in dataContext.GetQueryable<PlayedGame>()
              where playerGame.Id == testPlayerWithNoPlayedGames.Id
              let player = x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault().Player
              select new
              {
                  Name = player.Name,
                  Id = (int?)player.Id
              }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: At first I didn't believe you. My unit tests are blowing up... however, after digging into this quite a bit, you are in fact right. When running this query using EntityFramework directly against the DB this generates no errors! However, when setting up the data in a List<PlayedGame> and then querying the IQueryable (via .AsQueryable()), this actually blows up. So pure LINQ and EntityFramework behave differently in this regard! Here is a gist to demonstrate the difference: https://gist.github.com/jakejgordon/668ded9d18e7aaf513dfdf9d825c2d14

Comment: I've given up mocking/faking EF [long time ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13352779/861716). Only integration tests show the truth.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, you have many-to-many relation between `Player` and `PlayedGame` via `PlayerGameResult` table.

What you want to achieve is to get *any* relation from `PlayerGameResults` table for specific player.

Why not doing just that? For this you have to query `PlayerGameResults` table filtering by its player like this:

```
var result = dataContext.GetQueryable<PlayerGameResults>()
    .Where(player => player.Player.Id == testPlayerWithNoPlayedGames.Id)
    .Select(x => new {
        Name = x.Player.Name,
        Id = x.Player.Id,
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

**UPDATE** based on comments discussion

As we're working with database basically, not with C# (while still writing I would say "SQL with C# tokens"), we have to think on database terms.

That's why it is essential to understand that you are selecting specific row from a table, and basically based on what you described it is logic to select row from many-to-many relation table `PlayerGameResult`

Sample from the accepted answer is a good "bad" sample, so I will be referring to [gist you shared](https://gist.github.com/jakejgordon/668ded9d18e7aaf513dfdf9d825c2d14) based on it (slightly formatting):

```
.Select(x => new AchievementRelatedPlayedGameSummary
{
    //--only pull records where the Player had rank -42 (i.e. none of the PlayerGameResults)
    WinningPlayerName = x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault(y => y.GameRank == -42).Player.Name,
    WinningPlayerId = x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault(y => y.GameRank == -42).Player.Id
})
```

Here we twice referring to (as we might think) the same row `x.PlayerGameResults.FirstOrDefault(y => y.GameRank == -42).Player`, but reality is that separate SQL will be generated **for each** of that lines. Samples again from your gist.

This one for the Player.Name (results in `[Project2].[Name]`):

```
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent2].[PlayerId] AS [PlayerId]
    FROM [dbo].[PlayerGameResult] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE ([Filter1].[Id] = [Extent2].[PlayedGameId]) AND (-42 = [Extent2].[GameRank]) ) AS [Limit1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Player] AS [Extent3] ON [Limit1].[PlayerId] = [Extent3].[Id]) AS [Project2]
```

And this one for Player.Id (results in `[Limit2].[PlayerId]` - see how EF optimizes that to not to join to table):

```
OUTER APPLY  (SELECT TOP (1) 
    [Extent4].[PlayerId] AS [PlayerId]
    FROM [dbo].[PlayerGameResult] AS [Extent4]
    WHERE ([Project2].[Id] = [Extent4].[PlayedGameId]) AND (-42 = [Extent4].[GameRank]) ) AS [Limit2]
```

And here comes devil - as we have un-ordered SQL, `SELECT TOP(1)` will return **any** record it like to. There's **no guarantee at all** that these two results will be based on the same row (thanks to EF - here we have results even from different tables!), so you might receive `Id` from one `Player`, and `Name` from another `Player`. Result depends on indexes existence and statistics accumulated, db load, SQL server version and its overall mood. You just cannot be sure - that's it.

Of course I don't know your particular data model, and maybe filtering by `GameRank` will always return single row no matter what - but that is something you should not base your assumptions on anyway, in general.

So I still suggest base you query on entity you select, something like this one

```
var result = dataContext.GetQueryable<PlayerGameResults>()
    .Where(x => x.PlayedGame.Id == playedGameId && x.GameRank == -42)
    .Select(x => new AchievementRelatedPlayedGameSummary
    {
        WinningPlayerName = x.Player.Name,
        WinningPlayerId = x.Player.Id
    }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: your idea is fair, and I think I led you down the wrong path with the variable names I had in my original example. I'm actually starting with a given PlayedGame.Id, not a Player.Id -- so I don't think I can start from PlayerGameResult since there are potentially many PlayedGameResult records per PlayedGame -- and I only want a single  row returned for a given PlayedGame

Comment: @jakejgordon that just means another condition in `Where` part to actually find this particular `PlayerGameResulst` record - what am I missing here?

Comment: maybe you can clarify in your answer?

Comment: Thanks @Lanorkin -- a very interesting point about the FirstOrDefault() possibly returning different  a different Player's information in both spots. I'll take steps to address that.

In regards to the final query -- I still need to pull back PlayedGame information and other stuff regardless of whether the PlayerGameResult exists. I thought this was unnecessary noise to include in the original question but I guess not. In other words, I should have said that we need to assume that we have to start with the PlayedGame table. Sorry about that and thanks for your effort!